# how to stop and reset slides.jquery.js

Tags: jquery, function, slidesjs

EDIT 4 July: Still struggling with this issue. I'm sure all that's required is a function that stops the slideshow based on the class 'playing', but uncertain how to create that function.

I'm using [slides.js](http://slidesjs.com/) on a single-page site with multiple slideshows. I had initially initialised the script within the head using the following:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(".slides").slides({
    play: 3000,
    fadeSpeed: 800,
    effect: 'fade'
    });
</script>
```

But I found that the multiple slideshows were behaving oddly, so I decided to have them play individually and initialised within another function (that controls the site content) like this:

```
activeID = this.id,

function playSlides() {
    $('.slides#' + activeID + '-slides').addClass('playing').slides({
    play: 3000,
    fadeSpeed: 800,
    effect: 'fade'
    });
}
```

This is working correctly the first time each slideshow is intialised, but on viewing a slideshow a second time after that, the images within the slideshow seem to disappear and twice the pagination numbers appear.

I'm sure the problem is that the slideshows need to be stopped and reset each time they've played.

So how do I go about stopping a slideshow that is playing? I tried calling the following function:

```
function stopSlides() {
    if($('.slides.playing')) {
        stop();
        $('.slides.playing').removeClass('playing');
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
function stopSlides() {
    if($('.slides').hasClass('playing')) {
        stop();
        $('.slides.playing').removeClass('playing');
    }
}
```

However, this does seem to do anything.  Please advise if I haven't been clear enough or need more info.  MTIA!

Script here:

```
/*
* Slides, A Slideshow Plugin for jQuery
* Intructions: http://slidesjs.com
* By: Nathan Searles, http://nathansearles.com
* Version: 1.1.8
* Updated: June 1st, 2011
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
(function($){
    $.fn.slides = function( option ) {
        // override defaults with specified option
        option = $.extend( {}, $.fn.slides.option, option );

        return this.each(function(){
            // wrap slides in control container, make sure slides are block level
            $('.' + option.container, $(this)).children().wrapAll('<div class="slides_control"/>');

            var elem = $(this),
                control = $('.slides_control',elem),
                total = control.children().size(),
                width = control.children().outerWidth(),
                height = control.children().outerHeight(),
                start = option.start - 1,
                effect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? option.effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[0],
                paginationEffect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[1],
                next = 0, prev = 0, number = 0, current = 0, loaded, active, clicked, position, direction, imageParent, pauseTimeout, playInterval;

            // animate slides
            function animate(direction, effect, clicked) {
                if (!active && loaded) {
                    active = true;
                    // start of animation
                    option.animationStart(current + 1);
                    switch(direction) {
                        case 'next':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current + 1
                            next = current + 1;
                            // if last slide, set next to first slide
                            next = total === next ? 0 : next;
                            // set position of next slide to right of previous
                            position = width*2;
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = -width*2;
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                        case 'prev':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current - 1
                            next = current - 1;
                            // if first slide, set next to last slide
                            next = next === -1 ? total-1 : next;                                
                            // set position of next slide to left of previous
                            position = 0;                               
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = 0;      
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                        case 'pagination':
                            // get next from pagination item clicked, convert to number
                            next = parseInt(clicked,10);
                            // get previous from pagination item with class of current
                            prev = $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li.'+ option.currentClass +' a', elem).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                            // if next is greater then previous set position of next slide to right of previous
                            if (next > prev) {
                                position = width*2;
                                direction = -width*2;
                            } else {
                            // if next is less then previous set position of next slide to left of previous
                                position = 0;
                                direction = 0;
                            }
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                    }

                    // fade animation
                    if (effect === 'fade') {
                        // fade animation with crossfade
                        if (option.crossfade) {
                            // put hidden next above current
                            control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                zIndex: 10
                            // fade in next
                            }).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    // animate container to height of next
                                    control.animate({
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed, function(){
                                        // hide previous
                                        control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                            display: 'none',
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                             
                                        // reset z index
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                                 
                                        // end of animation
                                        option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                        active = false;
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // hide previous
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // reset zindex
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            // fade animation with no crossfade
                            control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).fadeOut(option.fadeSpeed,  option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                // animate to new height
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    control.animate({
                                        // animate container to height of next
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed,
                                    // fade in next slide
                                    function(){
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                // if fixed height
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                        // fix font rendering in ie, lame
                                        if($.browser.msie) {
                                            $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }                                   
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                        }
                    // slide animation
                    } else {
                        // move next slide to right of previous
                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                            left: position,
                            display: 'block'
                        });
                        // animate to new height
                        if (option.autoHeight) {
                            control.animate({
                                left: direction,
                                height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')').outerHeight()
                            },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                control.css({
                                    left: -width
                                });
                                control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    zIndex: 5
                                });
                                // reset previous slide
                                control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    display: 'none',
                                    zIndex: 0
                                });
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                            // if fixed height
                            } else {
                                // animate control
                                control.animate({
                                    left: direction
                                },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                    // after animation reset control position
                                    control.css({
                                        left: -width
                                    });
                                    // reset and show next
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        zIndex: 5
                                    });
                                    // reset previous slide
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    // set current state for pagination
                    if (option.pagination) {
                        // remove current class from all
                        $('.'+ option.paginationClass +' li.' + option.currentClass, elem).removeClass(option.currentClass);
                        // add current class to next
                        $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ next +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);
                    }
                }
            } // end animate function

            function stop() {
                // clear interval from stored id
                clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
            }

            function pause() {
                if (option.pause) {
                    // clear timeout and interval
                    clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                    clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
                    // pause slide show for option.pause amount
                    pauseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        // clear pause timeout
                        clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                        // start play interval after pause
                        playInterval = setInterval( function(){
                            animate("next", effect);
                        },option.play);
                        // store play interval
                        elem.data('interval',playInterval);
                    },option.pause);
                    // store pause interval
                    elem.data('pause',pauseTimeout);
                } else {
                    // if no pause, just stop
                    stop();
                }
            }

            // 2 or more slides required
            if (total < 2) {
                return;
            }

            // error corection for start slide
            if (start < 0) {
                start = 0;
            }

            if (start > total) {
                start = total - 1;
            }

            // change current based on start option number
            if (option.start) {
                current = start;
            }

            // randomizes slide order
            if (option.randomize) {
                control.randomize();
            }

            // make sure overflow is hidden, width is set
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                overflow: 'hidden',
                // fix for ie
                position: 'relative'
            });

            // set css for slides
            control.children().css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0, 
                left: control.children().outerWidth(),
                zIndex: 0,
                display: 'none'
             });

            // set css for control div
            control.css({
                position: 'relative',
                // size of control 3 x slide width
                width: (width * 3),
                // set height to slide height
                height: height,
                // center control to slide
                left: -width
            });

            // show slides
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                display: 'block'
            });

            // if autoHeight true, get and set height of first slide
            if (option.autoHeight) {
                control.children().css({
                    height: 'auto'
                });
                control.animate({
                    height: control.children(':eq('+ start +')').outerHeight()
                },option.autoHeightSpeed);
            }

            // checks if image is loaded
            if (option.preload && control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').length) {
                // adds preload image
                $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                    background: 'url(' + option.preloadImage + ') no-repeat 50% 50%'
                });

                // gets image src, with cache buster
                var img = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src') + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();

                // check if the image has a parent
                if ($('img', elem).parent().attr('class') != 'slides_control') {
                    // If image has parent, get tag name
                    imageParent = control.children(':eq(0)')[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    // Image doesn't have parent, use image tag name
                    imageParent = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')');
                }

                // checks if image is loaded
                control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src', img).load(function() {
                    // once image is fully loaded, fade in
                    control.find(imageParent + ':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                        $(this).css({
                            zIndex: 5
                        });
                        // removes preload image
                        $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                            background: ''
                        });
                        // let the script know everything is loaded
                        loaded = true;
                        // call the loaded funciton
                        option.slidesLoaded();
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // if no preloader fade in start slide
                control.children(':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                    // let the script know everything is loaded
                    loaded = true;
                    // call the loaded funciton
                    option.slidesLoaded();
                });
            }

            // click slide for next
            if (option.bigTarget) {
                // set cursor to pointer
                control.children().css({
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                });
                // click handler
                control.children().click(function(){
                    // animate to next on slide click
                    animate('next', effect);
                    return false;
                });                                 
            }

            // pause on mouseover
            if (option.hoverPause && option.play) {
                control.bind('mouseover',function(){
                    // on mouse over stop
                    stop();
                });
                control.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    // on mouse leave start pause timeout
                    pause();
                });
            }

            // generate next/prev buttons
            if (option.generateNextPrev) {
                $('.' + option.container, elem).after('<a href="#" class="'+ option.prev +'">Prev</a>');
                $('.' + option.prev, elem).after('<a href="#" class="'+ option.next +'">Next</a>');
            }

            // next button
            $('.' + option.next ,elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                    pause();
                }
                animate('next', effect);
            });

            // previous button
            $('.' + option.prev, elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                animate('prev', effect);
            });

            // generate pagination
            if (option.generatePagination) {
                // create unordered list
                if (option.prependPagination) {
                    elem.prepend('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                } else {
                    elem.append('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                }
                // for each slide create a list item and link
                control.children().each(function(){
                    $('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'</a></li>');
                    number++;
                });
            } else {
                // if pagination exists, add href w/ value of item number to links
                $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('href', '#' + number);
                    number++;
                });
            }

            // add current class to start slide pagination
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ start +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);

            // click handling 
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem ).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            // click handling 
            $('a.link', elem).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$') - 1;
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            if (option.play) {
                // set interval
                playInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    animate('next', effect);
                }, option.play);
                // store interval id
                elem.data('interval',playInterval);
            }
        });
    };

    // default options
    $.fn.slides.option = {
        preload: false, // boolean, Set true to preload images in an image based slideshow
        preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif', // string, Name and location of loading image for preloader. Default is "/img/loading.gif"
        container: 'slides_container', // string, Class name for slides container. Default is "slides_container"
        generateNextPrev: false, // boolean, Auto generate next/prev buttons
        next: 'next', // string, Class name for next button
        prev: 'prev', // string, Class name for previous button
        pagination: true, // boolean, If you're not using pagination you can set to false, but don't have to
        generatePagination: true, // boolean, Auto generate pagination
        prependPagination: false, // boolean, prepend pagination
        paginationClass: 'pagination', // string, Class name for pagination
        currentClass: 'current', // string, Class name for current class
        fadeSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the fading animation in milliseconds
        fadeEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        slideSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        slideEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        start: 1, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        effect: 'slide', // string, '[next/prev], [pagination]', e.g. 'slide, fade' or simply 'fade' for both
        crossfade: false, // boolean, Crossfade images in a image based slideshow
        randomize: false, // boolean, Set to true to randomize slides
        play: 0, // number, Autoplay slideshow, a positive number will set to true and be the time between slide animation in milliseconds
        pause: 0, // number, Pause slideshow on click of next/prev or pagination. A positive number will set to true and be the time of pause in milliseconds
        hoverPause: false, // boolean, Set to true and hovering over slideshow will pause it
        autoHeight: false, // boolean, Set to true to auto adjust height
        autoHeightSpeed: 350, // number, Set auto height animation time in milliseconds
        bigTarget: false, // boolean, Set to true and the whole slide will link to next slide on click
        animationStart: function(){}, // Function called at the start of animation
        animationComplete: function(){}, // Function called at the completion of animation
        slidesLoaded: function() {} // Function is called when slides is fully loaded
    };

    // Randomize slide order on load
    $.fn.randomize = function(callback) {
        function randomizeOrder() { return(Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }
            return($(this).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $children = $this.children();
            var childCount = $children.length;
            if (childCount > 1) {
                $children.hide();
                var indices = [];
                for (i=0;i<childCount;i++) { indices[indices.length] = i; }
                indices = indices.sort(randomizeOrder);
                $.each(indices,function(j,k) { 
                    var $child = $children.eq(k);
                    var $clone = $child.clone(true);
                    $clone.show().appendTo($this);
                    if (callback !== undefined) {
                        callback($child, $clone);
                    }
                $child.remove();
            });
            }
        }));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working really well using Nathan Searle's [Slidejs 2](https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides). See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590795/how-to-stop-and-play-jquery-script) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best solution but I found one - well for my purposes anyways. I'm also using the Slides.js plugin and the client requested the slidshow stop on the last slide. So I used the animationComplete callback function to trigger a click event on the pagination (which stops the autoplay functionality).

```
$("#slides").slides({
    crossfade: false,
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeEasing: "easeOutQuad",
    fadeSpeed: 500,
    play: 6000, 
    animationComplete: function(){
        introSlides();
        if($('.pagination li:last').hasClass('current')){
            $('.pagination li:last a').trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Mike Cummings' answer was very helpful. Instead of a Click event, though, I used the slider's pause() function. So my code looks like this:

```
$("#slides").slides({
  crossfade: false,
  effect: 'fade',
  fadeEasing: "easeOutQuad",
  fadeSpeed: 500,
  play: 6000, 
  animationComplete: function() {
    if ($('.pagination li:last').hasClass('current')) {
      pause();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: for whatever reason, seven months later, the pause() function has stopped working for me. None of the code has changed. But it now says pause is undefined. After hours of fruitless attempts to figure this out, I have resorted to the click event solution Mike Cummings suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for my needs the beta version of slides 2.0 is rather unusable, it's true you can control the status ( pause, stop, play ) but the rest of the code is still in alfa stage I would say ;)

A few lines of code to slides 1.9 are needed to achieve what you need

[Check this post on slidesjs forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/slidesjs/pause/slidesjs/mR3Q_XApre0/hZC8Oz08qOYJ)

Cheers

Dario

Answer (score -1):

i think below code may be helpful,

this code is for stop slider

```
$( ".slides.playing" ).bind( "slidestop", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

then again you can start with below code.

```
$( ".slides.playing" ).bind( "slidestart", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Chandresh, I'm not really sure how this could help me. I need help with the function that would actually stop and reset the slideshow.