# How to stop and play jquery script

Tags: jquery, function

I'm using [slidesjs](http://www.slidesjs.com/) to create 5 different slideshows/galleries on a single-page site. They all have the class '.slides' and have their own ID.

I do not want any of the slideshows to play until a play function is called. I've been able to successfully prevent each slideshow from playing onload using the following:

```
    function initiateSlides() {
    $('.slides').slides({
        generateNextPrev: true,
        fadeSpeed: 800,
        hoverPause: true,
        play: 3000,
        pause: 2500,
        preloadImage: 'images/loading.gif',
        effect: 'fade'
    });
    clearInterval($('#projects-commercial-slides').data('interval'));
    clearInterval($('#projects-residential-slides').data('interval'));
    clearInterval($('#projects-hospitality-slides').data('interval'));
    clearInterval($('#projects-public-slides').data('interval'));
    clearInterval($('#projects-industrial-slides').data('interval'));
}
```

(Using class '.slides' does not stop the slideshows, hence using IDs.) However, I'm now unable to play any of the slideshows.  I've tried the following:

```
function playSlides() {
    $('#projects-residential-slides').animate();
}

function playSlides() {
    $('#projects-residential-slides').play();
}

function playSlides() {
    $('#projects-residential-slides').animate({
        animationStart:0
        });
}

function playSlides() {
    $('#projects-residential-slides').animate('next',fade);
}
```

Your suggestions would be gratefully received as I've been working on this for days now(!). I appreciate I may not be preventing the slideshows from playing in the most elegant way. The full slides.jquery.js is here:

```
    /*
* Slides, A Slideshow Plugin for jQuery
* Intructions: http://slidesjs.com
* By: Nathan Searles, http://nathansearles.com
* Version: 1.1.8
* Updated: June 1st, 2011
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
(function($){
    $.fn.slides = function( option ) {
        // override defaults with specified option
        option = $.extend( {}, $.fn.slides.option, option );

        return this.each(function(){
            // wrap slides in control container, make sure slides are block level
            $('.' + option.container, $(this)).children().wrapAll('<div class="slides_control"/>');

            var elem = $(this),
                control = $('.slides_control',elem),
                total = control.children().size(),
                width = control.children().outerWidth(),
                height = control.children().outerHeight(),
                start = option.start - 1,
                effect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? option.effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[0],
                paginationEffect = option.effect.indexOf(',') < 0 ? effect : option.effect.replace(' ', '').split(',')[1],
                next = 0, prev = 0, number = 0, current = 0, loaded, active, clicked, position, direction, imageParent, pauseTimeout, playInterval;

            // animate slides
            function animate(direction, effect, clicked) {
                if (!active && loaded) {
                    active = true;
                    // start of animation
                    option.animationStart(current + 1);
                    switch(direction) {
                        case 'next':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current + 1
                            next = current + 1;
                            // if last slide, set next to first slide
                            next = total === next ? 0 : next;
                            // set position of next slide to right of previous
                            position = width*2;
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = -width*2;
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                        case 'prev':
                            // change current slide to previous
                            prev = current;
                            // get next from current - 1
                            next = current - 1;
                            // if first slide, set next to last slide
                            next = next === -1 ? total-1 : next;                                
                            // set position of next slide to left of previous
                            position = 0;                               
                            // distance to slide based on width of slides
                            direction = 0;      
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                        case 'pagination':
                            // get next from pagination item clicked, convert to number
                            next = parseInt(clicked,10);
                            // get previous from pagination item with class of current
                            prev = $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li.'+ option.currentClass +' a', elem).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                            // if next is greater then previous set position of next slide to right of previous
                            if (next > prev) {
                                position = width*2;
                                direction = -width*2;
                            } else {
                            // if next is less then previous set position of next slide to left of previous
                                position = 0;
                                direction = 0;
                            }
                            // store new current slide
                            current = next;
                        break;
                    }

                    // fade animation
                    if (effect === 'fade') {
                        // fade animation with crossfade
                        if (option.crossfade) {
                            // put hidden next above current
                            control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                zIndex: 10
                            // fade in next
                            }).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    // animate container to height of next
                                    control.animate({
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed, function(){
                                        // hide previous
                                        control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                            display: 'none',
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                             
                                        // reset z index
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                            zIndex: 0
                                        });                                 
                                        // end of animation
                                        option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                        active = false;
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // hide previous
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).css({
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // reset zindex
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).css({
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });                                 
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            // fade animation with no crossfade
                            control.children(':eq('+ prev +')', elem).fadeOut(option.fadeSpeed,  option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                // animate to new height
                                if (option.autoHeight) {
                                    control.animate({
                                        // animate container to height of next
                                        height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).outerHeight()
                                    }, option.autoHeightSpeed,
                                    // fade in next slide
                                    function(){
                                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing);
                                    });
                                } else {
                                // if fixed height
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')', elem).fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                                        // fix font rendering in ie, lame
                                        if($.browser.msie) {
                                            $(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }                                   
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                        }
                    // slide animation
                    } else {
                        // move next slide to right of previous
                        control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                            left: position,
                            display: 'block'
                        });
                        // animate to new height
                        if (option.autoHeight) {
                            control.animate({
                                left: direction,
                                height: control.children(':eq('+ next +')').outerHeight()
                            },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                control.css({
                                    left: -width
                                });
                                control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    zIndex: 5
                                });
                                // reset previous slide
                                control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                    left: width,
                                    display: 'none',
                                    zIndex: 0
                                });
                                // end of animation
                                option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                active = false;
                            });
                            // if fixed height
                            } else {
                                // animate control
                                control.animate({
                                    left: direction
                                },option.slideSpeed, option.slideEasing, function(){
                                    // after animation reset control position
                                    control.css({
                                        left: -width
                                    });
                                    // reset and show next
                                    control.children(':eq('+ next +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        zIndex: 5
                                    });
                                    // reset previous slide
                                    control.children(':eq('+ prev +')').css({
                                        left: width,
                                        display: 'none',
                                        zIndex: 0
                                    });
                                    // end of animation
                                    option.animationComplete(next + 1);
                                    active = false;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    // set current state for pagination
                    if (option.pagination) {
                        // remove current class from all
                        $('.'+ option.paginationClass +' li.' + option.currentClass, elem).removeClass(option.currentClass);
                        // add current class to next
                        $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ next +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);
                    }
                }
            } // end animate function

            function stop() {
                // clear interval from stored id
                clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
            }

            function pause() {
                if (option.pause) {
                    // clear timeout and interval
                    clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                    clearInterval(elem.data('interval'));
                    // pause slide show for option.pause amount
                    pauseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        // clear pause timeout
                        clearTimeout(elem.data('pause'));
                        // start play interval after pause
                        playInterval = setInterval( function(){
                            animate("next", effect);
                        },option.play);
                        // store play interval
                        elem.data('interval',playInterval);
                    },option.pause);
                    // store pause interval
                    elem.data('pause',pauseTimeout);
                } else {
                    // if no pause, just stop
                    stop();
                }
            }

            // 2 or more slides required
            if (total < 2) {
                return;
            }

            // error corection for start slide
            if (start < 0) {
                start = 0;
            }

            if (start > total) {
                start = total - 1;
            }

            // change current based on start option number
            if (option.start) {
                current = start;
            }

            // randomizes slide order
            if (option.randomize) {
                control.randomize();
            }

            // make sure overflow is hidden, width is set
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                overflow: 'hidden',
                // fix for ie
                position: 'relative'
            });

            // set css for slides
            control.children().css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0, 
                left: control.children().outerWidth(),
                zIndex: 0,
                display: 'none'
             });

            // set css for control div
            control.css({
                position: 'relative',
                // size of control 3 x slide width
                width: (width * 3),
                // set height to slide height
                height: height,
                // center control to slide
                left: -width
            });

            // show slides
            $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                display: 'block'
            });

            // if autoHeight true, get and set height of first slide
            if (option.autoHeight) {
                control.children().css({
                    height: 'auto'
                });
                control.animate({
                    height: control.children(':eq('+ start +')').outerHeight()
                },option.autoHeightSpeed);
            }

            // checks if image is loaded
            if (option.preload && control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').length) {
                // adds preload image
                $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                    background: 'url(' + option.preloadImage + ') no-repeat 50% 50%'
                });

                // gets image src, with cache buster
                var img = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src') + '?' + (new Date()).getTime();

                // check if the image has a parent
                if ($('img', elem).parent().attr('class') != 'slides_control') {
                    // If image has parent, get tag name
                    imageParent = control.children(':eq(0)')[0].tagName.toLowerCase();
                } else {
                    // Image doesn't have parent, use image tag name
                    imageParent = control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')');
                }

                // checks if image is loaded
                control.find('img:eq(' + start + ')').attr('src', img).load(function() {
                    // once image is fully loaded, fade in
                    control.find(imageParent + ':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                        $(this).css({
                            zIndex: 5
                        });
                        // removes preload image
                        $('.' + option.container, elem).css({
                            background: ''
                        });
                        // let the script know everything is loaded
                        loaded = true;
                        // call the loaded funciton
                        option.slidesLoaded();
                    });
                });
            } else {
                // if no preloader fade in start slide
                control.children(':eq(' + start + ')').fadeIn(option.fadeSpeed, option.fadeEasing, function(){
                    // let the script know everything is loaded
                    loaded = true;
                    // call the loaded funciton
                    option.slidesLoaded();
                });
            }

            // click slide for next
            if (option.bigTarget) {
                // set cursor to pointer
                control.children().css({
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                });
                // click handler
                control.children().click(function(){
                    // animate to next on slide click
                    animate('next', effect);
                    return false;
                });                                 
            }

            // pause on mouseover
            if (option.hoverPause && option.play) {
                control.bind('mouseover',function(){
                    // on mouse over stop
                    stop();
                });
                control.bind('mouseleave',function(){
                    // on mouse leave start pause timeout
                    pause();
                });
            }

            // generate next/prev buttons
            if (option.generateNextPrev) {
                $('.' + option.container, elem).after('<a href="#" class="'+ option.prev +'">Prev</a>');
                $('.' + option.prev, elem).after('<a href="#" class="'+ option.next +'">Next</a>');
            }

            // next button
            $('.' + option.next ,elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                    pause();
                }
                animate('next', effect);
            });

            // previous button
            $('.' + option.prev, elem).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                animate('prev', effect);
            });

            // generate pagination
            if (option.generatePagination) {
                // create unordered list
                if (option.prependPagination) {
                    elem.prepend('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                } else {
                    elem.append('<ul class='+ option.paginationClass +'></ul>');
                }
                // for each slide create a list item and link
                control.children().each(function(){
                    $('.' + option.paginationClass, elem).append('<li><a href="#'+ number +'">'+ (number+1) +'</a></li>');
                    number++;
                });
            } else {
                // if pagination exists, add href w/ value of item number to links
                $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('href', '#' + number);
                    number++;
                });
            }

            // add current class to start slide pagination
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li:eq('+ start +')', elem).addClass(option.currentClass);

            // click handling 
            $('.' + option.paginationClass + ' li a', elem ).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$');
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            // click handling 
            $('a.link', elem).click(function(){
                // pause slideshow
                if (option.play) {
                     pause();
                }
                // get clicked, pass to animate function                    
                clicked = $(this).attr('href').match('[^#/]+$') - 1;
                // if current slide equals clicked, don't do anything
                if (current != clicked) {
                    animate('pagination', paginationEffect, clicked);
                }
                return false;
            });

            if (option.play) {
                // set interval
                playInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    animate('next', effect);
                }, option.play);
                // store interval id
                elem.data('interval',playInterval);
            }
        });
    };

    // default options
    $.fn.slides.option = {
        preload: false, // boolean, Set true to preload images in an image based slideshow
        preloadImage: '/img/loading.gif', // string, Name and location of loading image for preloader. Default is "/img/loading.gif"
        container: 'slides_container', // string, Class name for slides container. Default is "slides_container"
        generateNextPrev: false, // boolean, Auto generate next/prev buttons
        next: 'next', // string, Class name for next button
        prev: 'prev', // string, Class name for previous button
        pagination: true, // boolean, If you're not using pagination you can set to false, but don't have to
        generatePagination: true, // boolean, Auto generate pagination
        prependPagination: false, // boolean, prepend pagination
        paginationClass: 'pagination', // string, Class name for pagination
        currentClass: 'current', // string, Class name for current class
        fadeSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the fading animation in milliseconds
        fadeEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        slideSpeed: 350, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        slideEasing: '', // string, must load jQuery's easing plugin before http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
        start: 1, // number, Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
        effect: 'slide', // string, '[next/prev], [pagination]', e.g. 'slide, fade' or simply 'fade' for both
        crossfade: false, // boolean, Crossfade images in a image based slideshow
        randomize: false, // boolean, Set to true to randomize slides
        play: 0, // number, Autoplay slideshow, a positive number will set to true and be the time between slide animation in milliseconds
        pause: 0, // number, Pause slideshow on click of next/prev or pagination. A positive number will set to true and be the time of pause in milliseconds
        hoverPause: false, // boolean, Set to true and hovering over slideshow will pause it
        autoHeight: false, // boolean, Set to true to auto adjust height
        autoHeightSpeed: 350, // number, Set auto height animation time in milliseconds
        bigTarget: false, // boolean, Set to true and the whole slide will link to next slide on click
        animationStart: function(){}, // Function called at the start of animation
        animationComplete: function(){}, // Function called at the completion of animation
        slidesLoaded: function() {} // Function is called when slides is fully loaded
    };

    // Randomize slide order on load
    $.fn.randomize = function(callback) {
        function randomizeOrder() { return(Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }
            return($(this).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $children = $this.children();
            var childCount = $children.length;
            if (childCount > 1) {
                $children.hide();
                var indices = [];
                for (i=0;i<childCount;i++) { indices[indices.length] = i; }
                indices = indices.sort(randomizeOrder);
                $.each(indices,function(j,k) { 
                    var $child = $children.eq(k);
                    var $clone = $child.clone(true);
                    $clone.show().appendTo($this);
                    if (callback !== undefined) {
                        callback($child, $clone);
                    }
                $child.remove();
            });
            }
        }));
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Doesn't _not_ setting the `play` option cause it to not autoplay?

Comment: You're right - it does, but using `'function playSlides() { $('#projects-residential-slides').slides({ play: 3000 }); } ` does not play the slideshow and instead creates multiple instances of the pagination (weirdly). I thought it would be best to initiate all the slideshows by using `play`. In that way I thought it (in theory) should be easy enough to stop/pause/play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest using (or taking a look at) Slidejs 2 https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides.

Reason none of of what you're trying is working is because he never exposes those methods you're trying to call (some don't even exist). Calling slides without the play option will prevent autoplaying, but it will also initialize slidejs (wrapping the children of the container). Calling it again later will re-initialize it thus resulting it the double wrapping you mentioned.

In version 2, he added an API that would work for you:

```
// With slidejs2
// stopping all slides
$(".slides").each(function() { $(this).slides("stop"); });
// playing all slides
$(".slides").each(function() { $(this).slides("play"); });
```

Aside from that, you clearInterval code could also be written as:

```
$('.slides').each(function() { clearInterval($(this).data("interval")); });
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, it seems as though slides2 uses ID rather than classes, making it a little more difficult... Will give it a go.

Comment: @circey I think it should still work with your class but if not, no reason you still can't do `$('.slides').each(function() { $(this).slides(options); });`

Comment: I can't even get the example working with fade, which is required. [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w9YV6/) with the original sample code but fade added to the options.   If I can't get this working, what chance multiple instances?!

Comment: @circey Heh. You're absolutely right, but remember, slidejs2 is still in beta. Nevertheless, I figured out what he's missing and added it in for you. Checkout the example at http://so.savantcoding.com/slidejs2/. Take a look at http://so.savantcoding.com/slidejs2/slidesjs2-custom.js and search for `@circey`. The lines following that are the lines I added and are the ones you need.

Comment: Thanks Phil for your help on this, but the slideshows I use will have to autostart and it appears that the fade effect works only on the pagination. I'm going to accept yours as my accepted answer and I think I'll have a go at something like bxslide. Many thanks Phil!

Comment: @circey I'm not content with it if you're not! Check it out now. It autoplays and the effect is fading.

Comment: Hi Phil, took me a while but I got around to looking at this again - what you've suggested works really well. I got several slide galleries working on a single page and all stop and play very well. The only issue that I have (and it's a minor issue) is that once a slide gallery has stopped, it does not "reset" and when playing for a second time plays from the last played slide. Ideally, I'd like it to reset and play from slide 1. But as I said, this is a minor issue ! Many thanks for your persistance and assistance!