# Disable "wrap around" in SlidesJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidesjs

I'm using [SlidesJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/), which is a very customizable plugin for pagination of slideshows.

This is my initialization.

```
$('.slides').slidesjs
({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    navigation: false,             // It's for swiping in an iOS web app
    pagination: false,
    generatePagination: false
});
```

However, I don't want the slideshow to wrap "the other way around". I don't know if there is a term for this, so I painted this illustration:

> Green = Next
>   Blue = Previous

[image: slidesjs wraparound]

What I want is the swipes which go from `4 -> 1` or from `1 -> 4` to be disabled. I haven't found a built in feature or property for this. But, **is there a reasonable workaround?**

Comment: Do you mean that once slideshow reaches `#4` the slideshow should be disabled?

Comment: You sould be able to go from 4 to 3, but not from 4 to one by swiping to the right. Maybe "overflowing" is the right term here?

Comment: Have not tried `slidejs`, though documentation provides a `complete` callback for each slide where `number` is slide number at end of animation. If `#4` is reached you could disable or reset slideshow? Is expected result `#1` ->`#4`, `#4` -> `#3`? Or stop at `#4`, stop at `#1`?

Comment: This callback could potentially work, but some of the slides only have two pages, so comparing numbers would not tell me the direction swiped.

Comment: Have a look at line 451 of `jquery.slide.js` I think the key is there. I just downloaded it... so... Don't ask me what to do next!! lol But this looks like what you need to fix : `if (next === this.data.total) {next = 0;}`

Comment: Line 451 appears to be within body  `._slide` function. You could probably implement process without using a plugin

Comment: @guest271314 I' talking about line 451 of the downloaded .zip file `jquery.slide.js` from http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: If I understood, this can be helpfull http://thinsoldier.github.io/externals/slidesjs/examples/thn-validate-before-next/

Comment: https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/blob/SlidesJS-3/source/jquery.slides.js#L451 ?

Comment: Exactly @guest271314... I think this is the key. But what to do with it depends on what bytecode77 wants to do... ;)

Comment: @daremachine this doesn't work with swiping (tested in Chrome dev tools) ; guest271314 this is the right place, but just changing the lines will result in strange behavior. There's probably a lot more to change, which I'm currently looking into.

Comment: The big question is what do you want to happen when last image is diplayed + left swipe. (Same question for first image + right swipe)... Just disable ? Like no swipe effect ?

Comment: @bytecode77 callback, it tell you direction in start is different number than complete right?

Comment: look for idea on Mike answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543478/how-to-stop-and-reset-slides-jquery-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Guys! I made it.**
*It took a couple hours.*

The initial recreated problem is [**here**](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/38406561/2016-07-14-jsSlides.html)

And my working solution, as explained below, is [**here**](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/38406561/2016-07-14-jsSlides-with-looping-option.html).

I found where to put a switch to this looping effect.
**AND** I setted it as a new `option` ==> `looping` (true/false) !!!
If the `looping` option is set to false... It won't loop.

```
defaults = {
  width: 940,
  height: 528,
  start: 1,
  navigation: {
    active: true,
    effect: "slide"
  },
  pagination: {
    active: true,
    effect: "slide"
  },
  play: {
    active: false,
    effect: "slide",
    interval: 5000,
    auto: false,
    swap: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    restartDelay: 2500
  },
  effect: {
    slide: {
      speed: 500
    },
    fade: {
      speed: 300,
      crossfade: true
    }
  },
  callback: {
    loaded: function() {},
    start: function() {},
    complete: function() {}
  },
  looping: false                    // Looping effect from last image to first and vice-versa
};
```

I **slightly modified** the `Plugin.prototype._slide` function to achieve this.
I added a new condition based on a `var` which I called `OK_Proceed`.

This var is `true` by default.
Its value becomes false when trying to go to the image index `-1` or `data.total`... But only if the looping option is set to false.

I wished to preserve the original function...
;)

```
var OK_Proceed=true;                                // ADDED var
    console.log( this.options.looping );
    if (next === -1) {
      if( this.options.looping ){
        next = this.data.total - 1;
      }else{
          OK_Proceed=false;
      }
    }
    if (next === this.data.total) {
      if( this.options.looping ){
          next = 0;
      }else{
          OK_Proceed=false;
      }
    }
```

When this `OK_Proceed` is false : The script bypasses the animate function entierely.
It is replaced by a small 10px "bounce" effect.

The only thing left to do is to reset the `data.animating` value:

```
$.data(_this, "animating", false);
```

So here is the full function:

```
Plugin.prototype._slide = function(number) {            console.log("Line 430 - _slide: ");
  var $element, currentSlide, direction, duration, next, prefix, slidesControl, timing, transform, value,
    _this = this;
  $element = $(this.element);
  this.data = $.data(this);                             console.log( JSON.stringify( $.data(this) ) );
  if (!this.data.animating && number !== this.data.current + 1) {
    $.data(this, "animating", true);
    currentSlide = this.data.current;               console.log("Line 437 - currentSlide: "+currentSlide);
    if (number > -1) {
      number = number - 1;
      value = number > currentSlide ? 1 : -1;               console.log("Line 440 - value: "+value);
      direction = number > currentSlide ? -this.options.width : this.options.width;
      next = number;
    } else {
      value = this.data.direction === "next" ? 1 : -1;
      direction = this.data.direction === "next" ? -this.options.width : this.options.width;
      next = currentSlide + value;                  console.log("Line 446 - next: "+next);
    }   var OK_Proceed=true;                                // ADDED var
    console.log( this.options.looping );
    if (next === -1) {
      if( this.options.looping ){
        next = this.data.total - 1;
      }else{
          OK_Proceed=false;
      }
    }
    if (next === this.data.total) {
      if( this.options.looping ){
          next = 0;
      }else{
          OK_Proceed=false;
      }
    }
    if(OK_Proceed){this._setActive(next);                           // ADDED condition
    slidesControl = $(".slidesjs-control", $element);
    if (number > -1) {
      slidesControl.children(":not(:eq(" + currentSlide + "))").css({
        display: "none",
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 0
      });
    }
    slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
      display: "block",
      left: value * this.options.width,
      zIndex: 10
    });
    this.options.callback.start(currentSlide + 1);
    if (this.data.vendorPrefix) {
      prefix = this.data.vendorPrefix;
      transform = prefix + "Transform";
      duration = prefix + "TransitionDuration";
      timing = prefix + "TransitionTimingFunction";
      slidesControl[0].style[transform] = "translateX(" + direction + "px)";
      slidesControl[0].style[duration] = this.options.effect.slide.speed + "ms";
      return slidesControl.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd", function() {
        slidesControl[0].style[transform] = "";
        slidesControl[0].style[duration] = "";
        slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
          left: 0
        });
        slidesControl.children(":eq(" + currentSlide + ")").css({
          display: "none",
          left: 0,
          zIndex: 0
        });
        $.data(_this, "current", next);
        $.data(_this, "animating", false);
        slidesControl.unbind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd");
        slidesControl.children(":not(:eq(" + next + "))").css({
          display: "none",
          left: 0,
          zIndex: 0
        });
        if (_this.data.touch) {
          _this._setuptouch();
        }
        return _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1);
      });
    } else {
      return slidesControl.stop().animate({
        left: direction
      }, this.options.effect.slide.speed, (function() {
        slidesControl.css({
          left: 0
        });
        slidesControl.children(":eq(" + next + ")").css({
          left: 0
        });
        return slidesControl.children(":eq(" + currentSlide + ")").css({
          display: "none",
          left: 0,
          zIndex: 0
        }, $.data(_this, "current", next), $.data(_this, "animating", false), _this.options.callback.complete(next + 1));
      }));
    } } else { 
    console.log("HERE");
    $.data(_this, "animating", false);
    console.log( JSON.stringify( $.data(this) ) );

    // Bouncing effect
    $(".slidesjs-control").stop().animate( { "left" : "-=10px" }, 100, "easeInOutBounce", function(){
        $(".slidesjs-control").animate( { "left" : "+=10px" }, 100, "easeInOutBounce");
    });

     }                      // End added condition
  }
};
```

I cleaned this code from all the console.logs and created a [zip file ready to use](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/38406561/zip/SlidesJS-with-looping-option.zip).

**The day after EDIT**
There was two other functions to modify in order to make the "touch" behave the same as mouse clicked links... The `.zip` file above also reflects these changes...

Function modified for click is : `_slide`.
Functions modified for click are : `_setuptouch` and `_touchmove`.

Two classes are available for you to modify : `bounceForward` and `bounceBackward`.

The [lastest demo is here](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/38406561/2016-07-14-jsSlides-with-looping-option2.html). Try it on a touch enabled device.

Comment: This is what I tried, too. And it causes wonky behavior so it's not entirely fixing it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to put this. Maybe *undefined behavior* is the right technical term here. Basically, a blank page is displayed.

Comment: Also instead of canceling the event and bringing back the page, I would rather bounce it, like if "there was nothing there". Just like bouncing is implemented in iOS with the page itself.

Comment: This line `value = this.data.direction === "next" ? 1 : -1;` is a clue (line 444). There is something about data "direction"

Comment: I just found that `this.data.direction` can hold one of these 2 values `next` or `previous`... See between lines 223 and 250. --- (I just added the @guest271314's github link.. for line refs... Thanks again guest271314 !!)

Comment: Hoo... Getting fuzzed here. See what hapens to `direction` on line 445: If value == next -> direction = `-this.options.width` else -> direction = `this.options.width`....... Then used on lline 474 as an integrer +px.... Ayayaille.... Am I getting lost ? .oO(lol)

Comment: At first, I would like to thank you for the effort you have spent on this! However, I tested it using Chrome dev tools and its touch feature. When overswiping, it doesn't bounce, but stays. Is there a solution to make it bounce?

Comment: You mean... To clearly show that the swipe has been triggered ? It could be added to the `else` part of the added condition... I guess.

Comment: It's hard to explain, but I'll make a video of it when I'm back home :)

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. I uploaded a video of what I mean here: http://sendvid.com/pin0ktd1

Comment: Outch! This really is surprising. ehw.... I think the fct `touchmove` also needs a fix. Did you try it on pc ?

Comment: Ok... I found something in `setuptouch` Hang on! ;)

Comment: Hey... I think I fixed the touch issue. Try this : https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/38406561/2016-07-14-jsSlides-with-looping-option2.html

Comment: Very close! :) Do you think you can implement bouncing as well?

Comment: Updated.... I could play a long time to make a smooter bounce effect... Maybe. I'll let you know When I'll be satisfied of it. ;)

Comment: That's not what I meant with bouncing. Bouncing is the effect that you get when you swipe down a list and try to swipe further than the actual list goes. Try it in any list and drag it to the bottom and then try to drag it further. It's hard to put in words, but I think this is my best way of putting it.

Comment: Where I actually am... Is that I added a class named `bounceBackward` when trying to swipe to picture "-1" and `bounceFoward` when trying to swipe to picture "total"... So the animation is in CSS @keyFrame. It could be whatever you want. I could update the .zip flie for you to play with. ;) But I still have a problem to fix since the image strangely don't *always* end at `left:0px`.

Comment: .zip file is upgraded on my server. Try it. ;) It the [same link](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/38406561/zip/SlidesJS-with-looping-option.zip) as in the answer... I made a readme.txt

Comment: For people to now... I fixed the @Keyframe 100% `left:0px` not always obeying with [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6210785/2159528) which I wish I could upvote more than once. :D

Comment: This is what I meant with bouncing: http://www.imagebam.com/image/2a28e5495462628 - Once you swipe too far, you can drag into an empty space until you remove your finger, then it moves back. How can this be applied to your solution?

Comment: I tried to use to value of "touchend - touchstart"... But it creates a strange bug when the image has been translated to more than the half of the screen. The plugin releases it as it was not the current image anymore. It becomes complex... If what I already done wasn't. ;) If I find something... I'll let you know for sure. But not today.

Comment: I think that playing with the @keyframe I "inserted" into it (in the HTML file) would simulate something close to what you want.

Comment: Anyway, you gave me a very good start and thank you so much for your time you spent on this! +1!!